# How can I base64 encode using a custom letter set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, encoding, base64

I am trying to base64 encode using a custom character set in python3. Most of the examples I have seen in SO are related to Python 2, so I had to make some minor adjustments to the code. The issue that I am facing is that I am replacing the character `/` with `_`, but it is still printing with `/`. My code is: This is just an example, i am not trying to only base64 with urlsafe chars. `custom` could be anything with the correct length.

```py
import base64

data = 'some random? data'
print(base64.b64encode(data.encode()))

std_base64chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
custom = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_"

data = data.translate(str.maketrans(custom, std_base64chars)).encode()

print(base64.b64encode(data))

# Both prints
b'c29tZSByYW5kb20/IGRhdGE='
b'c29tZSByYW5kb20/IGRhdGE='
```

How can I get the translation to work so that occurrences of `/` are replaced correctly with `_`?

### Edit

I should make it clear that I am not trying to do only one type of base64 encoding here like urlsafe, but any possible character set. This will be a function were a user can pass their own charset. I am looking for a character by character mapping, not string slicing.

### Edit

Because there is some confusion around the clarity of my question, I am try to add more details.

I am trying to write a function that can take an arbitrary charset from a user, and then map them individually before base64 encoding. Most of the answers have been around manipulating `altchars` or string slice and replace, but that doesnt solve all the needs.

So for example, the itoa64 charset is:
`./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz=` or unix crypt format is `./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. The answers although correct, does not address these situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only characters you want to switch are `+` and `\`, you can use [`base64.urlsafe_b64encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) to replace with `-` and `_` respectively.

```
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data.encode())
b'c29tZSByYW5kb20_IGRhdGE='
```

Alternatively, you can replace those characters with characters of your own choice using the optional argument of [`base64.b64encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode):

```
>>> base64.b64encode(data.encode(), '*&'.encode())
b'c29tZSByYW5kb20&IGRhdGE='
```

If you need to use an entirely new alphabet, you can do

```
import base64

data = 'some random? data'
print(base64.b64encode(data.encode()))

std_base64chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
custom = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_"


x = base64.b64encode(data.encode())
print(bytes(str(x)[2:-1].translate(str(x)[2:-1].maketrans(std_base64chars, custom)), 'utf-8'))
```

Which outputs:

```
b'c29tZSByYW5kb20/IGRhdGE='
b'C29TzsbYyw5KB20_igrHDge='
```

Comment: I should make it clear that I am not trying to do only one type of base64 encoding here like urlsafe, but any possible character set. I updated the OP

Comment: Thanks for the update @CDJB. But this kind of string slicing does not address things like itoa64 where there are some special chars at the beginning of the charset. I am looking more for a character by character mapping

Comment: You are right. That solution does work for me. I accept it as the answer. Sorry about the trouble.

Comment: @CDJB Would you kindly add how to revert back to original, that is, decode using the same `custom` chars?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this work:

```
import base64


data = 'some random? data'

custom = b"-_"

rslt = base64.b64encode(data)
print(rslt)

rslt = base64.b64encode(data, altchars=custom)
print(rslt)
```

I get following output:

```
c29tZSByYW5kb20/IGRhdGE=
c29tZSByYW5kb20_IGRhdGE=
```

or if you insist, that custom contains:

```
custom = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_"
```

then use:

```
rslt = base64.b64encode(data, altchars=custom[-2:])
```

Comment: OK I see. documentation is a little funny:

Optional altchars must be a bytes-like object of at least length 2 .

and then it meantions, that all other chars are ignored.

I adapted my answer

Comment: I should make it clear that I am not trying to do only one type of base64 encoding here like urlsafe, but any possible character set.

Comment: yes this would be great, as your example mentions explictly

The issue that I am facing is that I am replacing the character / with _, but it is still printing with /

and your example just wants to change characters that can be changed with altchars.
I suggest to make this clearer in the question.

SO what you really want is to do a characterby character mapping. will write another answer for that.

Comment: @gelonida, string slicing is not the option here as this will not address things like itoa64 format where the chars starts with `./`