# How can I decode a base64 string using a custom letter set?

Tags: python, base64, decode

I am aware of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917280/how-can-i-base64-encode-using-a-custom-letter-set) that tells me how to encode using a method provided in the answers.

But Idk how to then decode what was encoded after running the file to encode some text.

## This is my code to encrypt.

```py
import base64

print("What would you like to encode? ")
data = input()

std_base64chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789/="
custom = "abzdefghkjolsniprqmtuvwyxcDBCAEGFHJKILMNOPTRSQUVXWZY0629851743-&"

x = base64.b64encode(data.encode())
print('Here is your code!: ' + str(x)[2:-1].translate(str(x)[2:-1].maketrans(std_base64chars, custom)))
```

How would I go about decoding the output/encrypted text of the above lines of code?.

## Output Example.

```
What would you like to encode? 
Hello World!
Here is your code!: mgvSBg4Fv23ZBgrH  <-- How do I decode that?
```

Comment: So you go data -> standard base64 encoding -> character set translation -> coded data, so wouldn't the obvious reverse operation be coded data -> inverse translation -> standard base64 decoding -> data?

Comment: @ilkkachu
So something like this?


print('Here is your code!: ' + str(x)[2:-1].maketrans(str(x)[2:-1].translate(custom, std_base64chars)))

Comment: @ilkkachu
Swapping those two gives me the following.

What would you like to decode? 
mgvSBg4Fv23ZBgrHkdPe
Here is your code!: \Y3A\Y0B\YD2\Y01\Y0E\Y05\YBFS\YD3\Y01\N\YZ7\Y36\YD9\YDE

And that doesn't look right.


Doing both changing definitions and the order of which they occur in the code for printing, gives the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to reverse your steps.

The transform is swapping your character sets, so swap them back.
Now you have a base64 encoded string which can be decoded into something human readable.

```
data = input()
x = str(data).translate(str(data).maketrans(custom, std_base64chars))
print(base64.b64decode(x).decode())
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked. I don't know why that didn't cross my mind but now I know for later endevours.

Comment: Hello, what if I don't know the custom letter set, is there a method to decode the encoded string?